# How to set BitmapDescriptor to image view?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I need to get default map marker and set that icon to image view.

```
BitmapDescriptor b=BitmapDescriptorFactory
                .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory. HUE_YELLOW);


        img.setBackground(b);
```

i have tried like above code, but i didnt get answer. Can you help me to solve this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: thank you, but there is no answer from that link shkschneider.

Comment: I know, but your question is a duplicate. Opening a bounty on it would not get this question flagged as duplicate.